# DUKPT - more specific materials

Tags: research

I'm working on a simple project that implements DUKPT. I've tried searching the web for more specific information than on wikipedia and it seems that the algorithms are only covered in ANSI X9.24 part 1. Are there any more sources (prefered free ofc)?

Comment: Sorry, but i think you'll have to spend some coin. After what happened to Aaron Schwartz, nobody is going to upload a copy of the standard.